# ADT plugin install sticks at 49% on Eclipse Classic 3.6

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am having a strange problem that the ADT plugin installation sticks at 49% on Eclipse Classic 3.6 for infinite time, as shown below...

[image]

Please help me out to solve this problem...

Thanks..

Comment: This has been asked a billion times, please search a bit before asking next time. Burak Dede is right.

Comment: I had searched everywhere but when I didn't get solution for my problem, thats why I asked a simple question, this is why forums are made, so stop commenting like it is asked billion times, if you don't have answer... y do people comment when they don't have answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a fresh Eclipse 3.6 just yesterday and also noticed this dialog froze up... until I moved the mouse pointer within it, at which point it magically woke up and continued.

To complete installation of ADT etc I merely had to wiggle the mouse a few dozen times on top of the dialog box. It was very odd behaviour, never saw 3.5 doing that.

Comment: Reuben, my luck didn't work with your suggestion, it still sticks at 49%, I tried to go into detail, and found following link which points to unavailable file, I think they have bug in their ADT plugin... http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xmlfile=/releases/helios/201006230900/aggregate/protocol=httpcountryCode=ustimeZone=5format=xml

Comment: Sorry about that, seems such a coincidence. You may want to try a clean install of JDK6u23, then Eclipse, then ADT and Android SDK

Answer (score 2):

I was also going throught the same problem when I was installing the "Android Development Tools" plugin. I just changed eclipse version from eclipse classic to Java EE helios and surprisingly it worked properly. Moreover I downloaded the plugins zip file from "http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html" under the section "Troubleshooting ADT Installation" instead of providing the "http://dl-ssl..." link. I hope this will prove helpful as it really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

As its said in android developer resource ADT plugin has still have some bugs , so its better to use ADT plugin with 3.5 Galileo.

I had try to use ADT plugin with Eclipse Helios under Ubuntu but i come across lots of problems , so i switch back to Galileo similar problem never occured...

Comment: I spent too much time to add ADT plugin on Eclipse Galilio (on windows) today, but it always resulted in "Cannot complete the install Software being installed: Android Development Tools  (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 8.0.1.v201012062107-82219)
  Missing requirement: Structured Text Model 1.1.401.v200909172215 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 1.1.401.v200909172215) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found", I tried googling it but with no luck, every body said go for Elicpse Classic 3.6, now I am getting 49% stuck error, how hard is my life :(

Comment: yeah I know that , it is pretty frustrating but as I said above ADT plugin works stable with Eclipse Galileo 3.5 , at least for me

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the menu 'Help'

2.Choose 'Install New Software'

3.Select Add...
 - Name = GEF SDK 
 - Location = http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

4.Choose the updates for the version of eclipse you have installed.

5.Click 'Next'

6.After Eclipse calculates all the dependencies, just click 'Finish' and let it install the plugin.